# Iterating through a file and replacing strings, leaving the number of characters intact

Tags: python, replace

I'm attempting to anonymize a file so that all the content except certain keywords are replaced with gibberish, but the format is kept the same (including punctuation, length of string and capitalization). For example:

```
I am testing this, check it out! This is a keyword: long
Wow, another line.
```

should turn in to:

```
T ad ehistmg ptrs, erovj qo giw! Tgds ar o qpyeogf: long
Yeg, rmbjthe yadn.
```

I am attempting to do this in python, but i'm having no luck in finding a solution. I have tried replacing via tokenization and writing to another file, but without much success.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: Show what have you tried please and what did you have difficulties with?

Comment: You say "anonymize". If you need to make sure that it's impossible to recover any of the scrubbed data, particularly if you have a legal duty to do so, you may want to speak to a subject matter expert rather than relying on random internet strangers who may not have any more of a clue than you do.

Comment: @user2357112 If he wanted to completely erase that data he would have used a strong encryption scheme, which however fails in his requirements of keeping string length, capitalization and spaces. BTW: this information is already quite useless to recover some useful data, even if not the actual content of the text... this is why in my answer I explictly provide a method that isn't trivially reversible, by using a different random key for each single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially let's disregard the fact that we have to preserve some keywords. We will fix that later.

The easiest way to perform this kind of 1-to-1 mapping is to use the method [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.translate#str.translate). The [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html) module also contains constants that contain all ASCII lowercase and uppercase characters, and [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle) can be used to obtain a random permutation.

```
import string
import random

random_caps = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
random_lows = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

random.shuffle(random_caps)
random.shuffle(random_lows)

all_random_chars = ''.join(random_lows + random_caps)

translation_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, all_random_chars)

with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    translated_contents = contents.translate(translation_table)

with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(translated_contents)
```

In python 2 the [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.translate#str.maketrans) is a function in the `string` module instead of a static method of `str`.

The `translation_table` is a mapping from characters to characters, so it will map every single ASCII character to an other one. The `translate` method simply applies this table to each character in the string.

**Important note**: the above method is actually *reversible*, because each letter its mapped to a unique other letter. This means that using a simple analysis over the frequency of the symbols it's possible to reverse it.

If you want to make this harder or impossible, you could re-create the `translation_table` for every line:

```
import string
import random

random_caps = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
random_lows = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'r') as f:
    translated_lines = []
    for line in f:
        random.shuffle(random_lows)
        random.shuffle(random_caps)
        all_random_chars = ''.join(random_lows + random_caps)

        translation_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, all_random_chars)
        translated_lines.append(line.translate(translation_table))

with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(translated_lines)
```

Also note that you could translate and save the file line by line:

```
with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        random.shuffle(random_lows)
        random.shuffle(random_caps)
        all_random_chars = ''.join(random_lows + random_caps)

        translation_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, all_random_chars)
        o.write(line.translate(translation_table))
```

Which means you can translate huge files with this code, as far as the lines themselves are not insanely long.

---

The code above messing *all* characters, without taking into account such keywords.

The simplest way to handle the requirement is to simply check for each line whether one of keywords occur and "reinsert" it there:

```
import re
import string
import random

random_caps = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
random_lows = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

keywords = ['long']   # add all the possible keywords in this list

keyword_regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in keywords))


with open('the-file-i-want.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        random.shuffle(random_lows)
        random.shuffle(random_caps)
        all_random_chars = ''.join(random_lows + random_caps)

        translation_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, all_random_chars)
        matches = keyword_regex.finditer(line)
        translated_line = list(line.translate(translation_table))

        for match in matches:
            translated_line[match.start():match.end()] = match.group()

        o.write(''.join(translated_line))
```

---

Sample usage (using the version that prevserves keywords):

```sh
$ echo 'I am testing this, check it out! This is a keyword: long
Wow, another line.' > the-file-i-want.txt
$ python3 trans.py 
$ cat output.txt 
M vy hoahitc hfia, ufoum ih pzh! Hfia ia v modjpel: long
Ltj, fstkwzb hdsz.
```

Note how `long` is preserved.

Comment: @DavidCullen Added a simple fix.

Comment: Good solution. I had gotten stuck on the keyword preservation, and hadn't thought of using a second pass like that.

Comment: @jimo337 I think it's the simplest solution and it's also quite efficient. In the end it would be rally hard to beat regexes to find those keywords, so the only other option would be to first find the keywords and then only `translate` the portions that aren't keywords, but this would be more cumbersome to do, and also I doubt that it would produce really significant changes in performance.